What's the difference between 小心 and 注意？
Can you explain the difference please?
Thank you in advance

Although both 小心 and 注意 have similar meanings, they may actually be quite different, depending on context. First, let's give a simple definition of both phrases:

小心: Be careful; be cautious; be mindful. 小心 is composed of the words 小, meaning small or little, and 心, which means heart or mind. However, combined, they do not mean "little heart". It is actually a description of having a small, cautious, and vigilant mind. Note that in Chinese, there had been a long tradition of using "heart" to refer to a person's mind. The opposite of 小心 is "粗心", meaning "careless".
注意: Pay attention; be aware. 注意 basically means either "to pay attention" or as a warning to potential danger ahead.

Similarities between 小心 and 注意:

Both can be used to tell a person to "be careful".
Both can be used as a warning.
Thus, in some contexts, they can be used interchangeably.

Difference between 小心 and 注意:

注意 is much more formal than 小心. Most official sources will use 注意 instead of 小心. For example, traffic symbols and road signs will use sentences like "注意駕駛安全: 通報酒駕" instead of "小心駕駛安全: 通報酒駕". 小心 is used in informal settings; for example, you might call out to a friend who's crossing the road to "小心車子!", rather than "注意車子!".
小心 is more related to immediate physical actions, while 注意 is more related to a mental orientation or concentration towards something that is worth (or requires) attention.
小心 is mostly used in a negative sense, meaning that you need to be careful to prevent a dangerous or bad situation from happening. 注意 does not necessarily imply a negative event that should be steered clear of. In fact, 注意 can be used in both positive and negative contexts. For example, 你必須注意到他的喜悦 ("you must recognize his joy"). Here, "注意" is used in a (somewhat) positive sense. Another neutral (neither positive nor negative), everyday-life example would be "注意回家的時候看一下雞蛋的價格" ("remember to check the price of eggs on your way home"). 注意 is mainly used in neutral everyday-life contexts like the one above.

Thus, in summary, while both 注意 and 小心 have somewhat same meaning in some contexts, they can actually differ a lot in other contexts.

A very comprehensive answer. How about an example of how 注意 can be used in a positive context?

@WayneCheah Thanks for reminding me, I'll edit my post to add an example of 注意 being used in a positive context.

@WayneCheah I just edited my answer to add the example sentences for 注意. Please check out.

小心 is a strange phrase.
小心 literally means small mind, but I think the idea is, focus on something, without distractions. (Not always easy!)
If you look up 小心，you find 注意 contained within the meaning of 小心。If you are “paying attention”, you are “being careful”.
小心：注意；留神。
注意：把心思、思想放到某一方面。
The difference is, 小心  is used when some kind of danger may be present, whereas 注意 may also be used for situations where no danger is likely.
女士们，先生们，请注意！
Ladies and gentlemen, please pay attention!
女士们，先生们，请小心！
Ladies and gentlemen, please be careful!

Occasionally you might hear people say "小心, 注意!", which means "Be careful, pay attention (to)". These are the basic meanings of the two phrases/words.
-

The difference is clear when they are used as verbs. When they are used as nouns, both can mean "warning" but with different degree

小心 = (v)be careful ; (n)caution --> warning of dangerous elements

Example:
小心落冰! (Caution: falling ice!)

注意 = (v)pay attention ; (n)caution / attention --> reminder of important issue (including dangerous elements)

Example:
注意! 前方急弯! (Caution! Sharp turn ahead!)
注意: 前方限速为 40 公里/小时 (Attention: 40km/h speed zone ahead)
